# Name of a certain topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, terminology, examples-counterexamples

Certain topological spaces have their own name. Topologist's sine curve, Hawaiian earring, the long line, the line with two origins and so on. Does the subspace $\{1/n \ \vert \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}\subseteq [0,1]$ have such a name?

Comment: I think it is called a *Peter space*.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'll call it a *Burden space* then.

Comment: Yes, it is called the 1-point compactification of $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000020

I usually just call it the "converging sequence", but in Steen/Seebach's *Counterexamples* they called it the "Countable Fort Space".